# How to create a Checkbox list data from database using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

guy's i need your help to solve my problem.
i want to make a checkboxlist using data from database but i need to use jquery for making it

before of it. 
i have an example of making a checkboxlist with php. i want to change it into jquery but i dont know how

this just a small of code for make a checkbox using php.
i want to make a code for making a checkboxlist but need to use jquery. is that possible to do that?

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="'.$stud.'" />Test
```

Comment: Do you have any PDO or DB connection coding already made?

Comment: i've made that.
i just need the jquery for calling the PHP function (include the DB conn and PDO) into a checkboxlist..

Comment: can you help me to give me an example of the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jQuery` you can generate dynamic checkboxes.

```js
for(var i=1;i<=6;i++){
    var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" name="chk_'+i+'" />Test '+i+"<br />");
    $("#box").append($chk);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: do you know how to change it into server side function?

Comment: because my data are from database.. 
the database table is `tb_data`
and the content is `no` and `name` 
the data that i want to retrieve into that textbox is the `name` data. can you help me how to make a jquery for that

Comment: thx dude..
i use your code and it work..
i just change it to this

`var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" name="chk_'+ list[i]['nama']  +'" />Test '+ list[i]['nama']  +"<br />");
      $("#multiselect").append($chk);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the checkbox in some html container.

```
<div id="append" name="append">Append here</div>
```

First you have to make ajax call it will give you response in array and then on that response you have to call each function which will dynamically append check boxes to html.

```
$.each(data,function(index,value){
    var checkbox_label = value;
    var checkbox_value =value;
    var checkbox_name = 'students['+index+']';
    var template = '<input type="checkbox" name="'+checkbox_name+'" value="'+checkbox_value+'">'+checkbox_label;

  $("#append").append(template);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/w2Lmqmcu/1/

```js
var data = ["Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4"]; // I'm expecting your data will be similar to this

$.each(data, function(index){
 $('.checkboxlist').append("<input type='checkbox' name='students[]' value='" + data[index] + "' />" + data[index] + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxlist">

</div>
```

Please update the question with your database response, so that we can answer it more accurately.

Comment: `$('body`) is it must be a class? can i change it into id's?

Comment: Yes you can change it into id by doing something like this $('#id').append();

Comment: oh.. i will try it 1st

Comment: i try to make my code like this but the data didnt showing xD

Comment: I looking for sample JSON or data that you are receiving from db, if you can provide that then i can help you out better.

Comment: i use data from a db @Shiladitya.

Comment: I understand that, but in the jsfiddle the url you are targeting using ajax will not work because the php location is your local location. Unless I see the exact format of the data I can't help you much. I need to see the data.

Comment: Not the php code buddy. You are using ajax call to get the data from database.. Right???? I need that data what you are receiving using ajax call.

Comment: The data i want to recieve from my database?
the data just from the table `name`

the table just contain `id [1],[2],[3],[4] and name [steve],[andy],[rody],[roy],[thomas]`

Comment: then the data i want to recieve is from column `name`